# Is it possible to use BC to ES adaptors in a custom light fixture?

Tags: wiring, lighting

I'd like to make my own light fixture. I have a BC to ES adaptor lying about and was wondering whether I could directly wire them to use with my ES bulb? Would it possible to just wire up the two bottom screws?
[image: BC to ES adaptor]

Answer (score 1):

There's really no reason that you couldn't. It won't be UL listed, of course, but folks have been cobbling their own lighting for decades. Use common sense with regard to connections, insulation, and wire sizing and protection and it should work fine.

One minor issue might be screw length, but you can almost certainly replace them with longer ones for a few nickels.